# I can not understand why the for loop becomes infinite?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, dynamic-programming

I can not understand why the loop becomes infinite. looked in the gdb and saw that after `i = 8` values of `i` again becomes `i = 4` but it is unclear why the changed.

```
#include <iostream>

int min_num_coins(int* v, int size, int w)
{
    int min[size];
    min[0] = 0;
    min[1] = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < w; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {
            if(v[j] <= i && min[i - v[j]] < min[i])
            {
                min[i] = min[i-v[j]];
            }
        }
    }
    return min[w];
}

int main()
{
    int v[] = {1, 3, 5};
    int w = 11;
    int size = sizeof(v)/sizeof(v[0]);
    int min = min_num_coins(v, size, w);
    std::cout << " min=: " << min << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the loop becomes infinite? This code appears to give `segfault` error.

Comment: No problem exactly in an infinite loop and there not a seg fault error.

Comment: Can you check my update?

Comment: I've already checked your updates and it works fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
if(v[j] <= i && min[i - v[j]] < min[i])
{
    min[i] = min[i-v[j]];
}
```

You are writing to `min[i]`. Your `i` could change up to `w-1`. `w` is 11, so `i` could change up to 10. But your `min` array size is `size` which is equal to 3.

Because of this when you are setting element out of `min`s bounds you are erasing stack data. Probably at some moment you are also erasing local variable `i` (which is also stored in stack) with new value 4.

UPDATE:

You can change

```
int min[size];
```

to

```
int min[size > w ? size : w];
```

to check.